# Grass is taller than the sky, and rubies are taller than grass - Who are we?

Tags: riddle

Grass is taller than the sky, and rubies are taller than grass,

We are three kings, three brothers of many, known to mankind since time immemorial,

Most men know all three of us, but some know fewer except perhaps by reputation,

Together we can create something pure.

**Who are we?**

Comment: Zelda (rubies are huge in the Zelda games) and the three pieces to complete the TriForce Sword? *lol*

Comment: @Radhato Nerdy!  I like it!  And actually, sort of close.  Sort of....  It works for the first three (usually, not in twilight princess though).  Maybe even the fourth sort of...  But not the ones after that.

Comment: It was the first thing that came to my mind ;) Was pretty sure it couldn't be right :P Looking forward to see the answer (or maybe even find it myself ^^)

Comment: I was thinking about Pokemon Leaf Green/Red and Blue :)

Comment: @ABcDexter and thinking that way pretty much got you the answer.  Videogames make you smart.  Its a fact! +1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I hope you are:

> Red, green and blue

Grass is taller than the sky, and rubies are taller than grass

> Green (grass) has longer wavelength than blue (sky), and red (rubies) has longer wavelength than green (grass)

We are three kings, three brothers of many, known to mankind since time immemorial

> The primary (kings) colours of light are red, green and blue and all colours are composed of these, for example the secondary colours 
>  Red + Blue = Magenta
>  Blue + Green = Cyan
>  Red + Green = Yellow

Most men know all three of us, but some know fewer except perhaps by reputation

> Most people can see all three but some men especially are colour blind and have a decreased ability to see colour, or perceive colour differences.

Together we can create something pure

> Together Red + Green + Blue in equal proportions = White which is called pure

Comment: Bingo tom.  Correct and well explained.  +1

Answer (score 5):

Are you:

> Gaspar, Balthasar, and Melchior?

Grass is taller than the sky,

> Only answer I don't know. Perhaps it has something to do with grass for the camels?

and rubies are taller than grass,

> They brought huge 'treasures' to the birth of jesus.
>  All three gifts are ordinary offerings and gifts given to a king. Myrrh being commonly used as an anointing oil, frankincense as a perfume, and gold as a valuable. The three gifts had a spiritual meaning: gold as a symbol of kingship on earth, frankincense (an incense) as a symbol of deity, and myrrh (an embalming oil) as a symbol of death.

We are three kings, three brothers of many, known to mankind since time immemorial,

> They are 3 brothers (of many more):
>
>  The tradition that there were three wise men arose from the fact that the Bible mentions three gifts, gold frankincense and myrrh according to Matthew 2:11. Howerver, the Bible doesn’t say how many wise men made the journey to see the baby Jesus. The unfounded idea that they were also kings came from the imagery of Isaiah 60:3.

Most men know all three of us, but some know fewer except perhaps by reputation,

> It's a christian holiday, so they know who they are. Other people with other believes, only know them by reputation (heard of from others).

Together we can create something pure.

> [Epiphany Holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday))

Comment: Only unsure about the grass is taller than the sky :<

Comment: Huh...  I didn't even know those guys had names!  Not what I was looking for but +1 for imagination and educationality.

Comment: @BrentHackers: They don't (at least not in the Bible). However, it was custom to go around the village and bless houses, after which they put chalk marks "CMB" above the door (Christe mansionem beneficat - may Christ bless this house). The names may have been a way to remember the letters, or the letters may have inspired the names.

Comment: @Jonas Even more educational! +1